# SQL: I want to calculate a value in a new column using two columns with the same name from separate tables

Tags: sql

What I want to do is this:

**January Table**

Cusip Number: 1 , 2, 3

Current Factor: .123, .140, .045

**February Table**

Cusip Number: 1, 2, 3

Current Factor: .184, .163, .033

Then a new column in the FEB table that finds the value of the Feb factor/jan factor for each CUSIP number:

=.123/.184

=.140/.163

etc..

This is what I have so far which pulls the factor from the previous month and displays it below the Feb Table

```
SELECT [CURRENT FACTOR]
FROM DBO.mbs012013, DBO.mbs022013
WHERE DBO.mbs012013.[CUSIP NUMBER] = DBO.mbs022013.[CUSIP NUMBER]
```

Comment: Need table structure, sample data, DB engine and version. And then, why have separate tables for months?

Comment: Duplicate post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193463/sqlusing-data-from-two-tables-with-the-same-column-name-and-more

Answer (score 1):

```
Update February 
  Set factor= (1.0 * January.factor/February.factor )
  from February 
  Join Janaury on .... whatever links Febuary to January which had better be a 1-1 join
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT February.CUSIP, February.factor, (1.0 * January.factor/February.factor ) as Ratio
  from February 
  INNER JOIN Janaury on January.CUSIP = February.CUSIP
```