# SQL:Using data from two tables with the same column name... and more

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What I want to do is this:

**January Table**

Cusip Number: 1 , 2, 3

Current Factor: .123, .140, .045

**February Table**

Cusip Number: 1, 2, 3

Current Factor: .184, .163, .033

Then a new column in the FEB table that finds the value of the Feb factor/jan factor for each CUSIP number:

=.123/.184

=.140/.163

etc..

This is what I have so far which pulls the factor from the previous month and displays it below the Feb Table

```
SELECT [CURRENT FACTOR]
FROM DBO.mbs012013, DBO.mbs022013
WHERE DBO.mbs012013.[CUSIP NUMBER] = DBO.mbs022013.[CUSIP NUMBER]
```

Comment: Create a new column with the values of the (feb table/jan table) in the feb table

Comment: I encourage you to think about how to generalize your schema. Having two tables with almost identical columns (and March will be just like February) is a code smell. Why not just have one table, with a column for ratio from previous month? Indeed, maybe you just want to recalculate that on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.[CUSIP NUMBER],
       b.[CURRENT FACTOR],
       a.[CURRENT FACTOR]/b.[CURRENT FACTOR] MyNewFieldName
FROM DBO.mbs012013 a, DBO.mbs022013 b
WHERE a.[CUSIP NUMBER] = b.[CUSIP NUMBER]
```

Comment: I think the / needs to be in single quotes here '/'.  Also, if he's creating a new field, he'll want to name that field, hence adding 'AS newField'

Comment: Kris, I am having trouble naming the new field. Where should I add the "AS newField" line?

Comment: I edited my answer, with new column names